# Move items in an array

Tags: javascript, three.js

Currently have sphere meshes in an array and would like to be able to place them in a level. Currently they are already set in a position (skeleton shaped) but I would like to move the whole array and place it in a location instead of individually moving each mesh. Is this possible?

```js
var meshJoints = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < 25 ; i++)
{
    var geo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.02, 18, 18);
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xCCCCCC});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
    meshJoints.push(mesh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all of your meshes to a [`Group`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group), then move the `Group`.

```js
var meshJoints = new THREE.Group();
for (var i = 0 ; i < 25 ; i++)
{
    var geo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.02, 18, 18);
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xCCCCCC});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
    meshJoints.add(mesh);
}

scene.add(group);
meshJoints.position.set(x, y, z); // setting group position will cascade to all children
```

A `Group` acts as a collection, and is its self transformable. Setting the position, rotation, or scale on a `Group` will cascade that change to all of its children. In this case, setting the `Group`'s `position` will cause all of your `Mesh`es to move by the same amount of change.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

If you merge these spheres using an extra geometry:

```
const mergedGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
mergedGeometry.merge(mesh1.geometry, mesh1.matrix);
```

you can just set the position of the merged mesh and they will all be repositioned. here is a codepen : https://codepen.io/ThanosSar/pen/JjRgyQz

> three.js documentation :
>
> https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Geometry :
>
> > ```
> > .merge ( geometry : Geometry, matrix : Matrix4, materialIndexOffset : Integer ) : null
> > Merge two geometries or geometry and geometry from object (using object's transform)
> > ```

**Method 2**

*EDIT : (with this method, meshes will remain independent and they will be able to be moved separately too)*

A second way is to create an object3d hierarchy by just :

```
fatherMesh.add(mesh1)
```

here is a codepen : https://codepen.io/ThanosSar/pen/VwKoMLw

> three.js documentation :
>
> https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D :
>
> > .add ( object : Object3D, ... ) : this
> > Adds object as child of this object. An arbitrary number of objects may be added. Any current parent on an object passed in here
> > will be removed, since an object can have at most one parent.